# How to modify table layout using linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am newer to the LINQ so it seems complicated to me.

I have this table in database:

[image]

I fetch the table records using LINQ to Entity:

```
  var inspectionsData = context.Set<inspectionsData>().ToList();
```

Now I need to made some logic to make inspectionsData look like that:

[image]

As you can see the **rows where Cities and Authority is the same I want them in one row with summed items**.
How can I make those changes using linq in c#?

Comment: Can you please post the Data Model for `inspectionsData`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this with a `GroupBy` statement, and then project to a new object using `Select`.

```
var result = context.Set<inspectionsData>()
                  .GroupBy(d => new {d.City, d.Authority})
                  .Select(g => new {g.Key.City, g.Key.Authority, Items = g.Sum(x => x.Items)})
                  .ToList();
```

That uses an anonymous object as the response, however as your response actually has the same shape as the initial object, you could also project back to `inspectionsData`:

```
var result = context.Set<inspectionsData>()
                  .GroupBy(d => new {d.City, d.Authority})
                  .Select(g => new inspectionsData{
                               City = g.Key.City, 
                               Authority = g.Key.Authority, 
                               Items = g.Sum(x => x.Items)})
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: @Jamic thank you for answer.But what if I have Authority table and it's related to the table above as many two many(I mean that Authority in related lookup table  )?